# ROS Answers SE migration: search in map

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , i made a 2Dmap for my turtlebot using gmapping, i want it to search for an object in the room that mapped , how can i do this Autonomously  ?
thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58376/search-in-map/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need to write a code which contains:

1. Visual recognition of the object (e.g. juice, book) that TurtleBot tries to recognize. This may be the most difficult part and I am still not sure which libraries are the most suitable. Perhaps RoboEarth detector?
2. Navigation implementation (not by rviz but directly from the code) which calls gmapping, acml, move_base, etc.
3. Main: the strategy designed by you (e.g. circulate the room according to a particular trajectory; when it sees the book then turns right, etc.) Alternatively you may try Explore stack.

Actually I am trying to do the same thing. Perhaps we can help each other :-)

My email is chik-david at brain.kyutech.ac.jp

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-03-22**:
Right ,, i am trying with my team to do this too ,, will contact u ,, thanks Chik